# Use Sequelize on for loop findAll query and merge result

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm coding opensource project in the university course

It is a function to search the value of another table by dividing input keyword by comma.

under this example data

> Python,CPP,Csharp

```
var keyword = result[0].keyword;
var keyword_arr = [];
var keyword_split = keyword.split(',');
for (var i in keyword_split)
{
   keyword_arr.push(keyword_split[i]);
}
```

I have succeeded in separating them with commas like above, but I'm looking for a loop in sequelize.

"Error: Can not set headers after they are sent."

An error is returned and is not executed.

I want to output the results merged. What should I do?

my code is

```
for (i = 0; i < keyword_arr.length; i++) {
    query += models.contents.findAll({
        where: {keyword: {like: '%' + keyword_arr[i] + '%'}},
        raw: true
    });
}
```

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were in the right direction , but here it his how you can do :

```
queries = [];

for (i = 0; i < keyword_arr.length; i++) {
    queries.push({keyword: {like: '%' + keyword_arr[i] + '%'}});
}

models.contents.findAll({
    where: {
        $or : queries
    }
    raw: true
}).then(results => {
    console.log(results); // <---- Check this
})
```

---

> **NOTES :**
>
> `models.contents.findAll() //<---- Returns promises`
>
> You can't just combine the promises by += as its not string or number
>   like that
>
> In your case , it will create and run the query for each tag , so
>   that's not proper way of doing , you should combine the tags and create a single query as I did

Comment: Happy Coding :)